# For a fiber bundle $f:M\to S^1$, is there a point whose horizontal lift is a circle?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: M\to S^1$ be a Riemannian submersion, and also a fiber bundle. $M$ may be non-compact, possibly with boundary. For $x\in S^1$, consider the fiber $f^{-1}(x)\subset M$. Is there a point $p\in f^{-1}(x)$, such that the horizontal lift of $S^1$ beginning at p also end at p? If $M$ is the Möbius band, there exist such points.

Comment: Every such bundle is a mapping torus of a self-diffeomorphisms of $f^{-1}(x)$. The horizontal lift you ask for exists if and only if this diffeomorphism has a fixed point. For $f^{-1}(x)=(-1,1)$ the Mobius bundle is induced by $t\mapsto -t$ which indeed has a fixed point.

Comment: @archipelago: For Mobius band, this surely holds. I ask the general case.

Comment: @mathmetricgeometry: archipelago has explained the general case: a mapping torus.

Comment: @archipelago: Thank you! Just consider the cyliner $f:S^1\times (-\infty,+\infty)\to S^1$, the diffeomorphisms of  $f^{-1}(x)$ is $(0,t)\to (1,t+1)$. Then the Horizontal lifting lines are spiral rising lines.

Comment: @archipelago: I think the above cylinder is not a counter example. Their Horizontal lifting are circles. Klein bottle to $S^1$ is a counter example, the fibers are $S^1$, the diff is reflexion, no fixed point. Need Horizontal lifting of base $S^1$ twice, then it's a closed curve.

Answer (score 1):

The 2-sheeted cover of the circle by itself is a counterexample.
By "the" horizontal lift, do you mean "a" horiontal lift? If so,
and if the fibres are connected, then the answer is positive.

Comment: The second assertion doesn't seem to be true: the Klein bottle (viewed as the non-orientable $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$) does not have a section.

Comment: I cannot agree, Marco. It does have a section (which is weaker than being a product).

Comment: Oops. Non-orientable things are confusing. You're right.